# Win Phone App: Possible to use event declared on another page?

Tags: c#, silverlight, class, windows-phone-7, events

My scenario is quite simple, in fact I thought it would cause no problem but it does, can anyone help?

My `MainPage` begins with this:

```
namespace PhoneApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage { /* snip */ }
}
```

Later in the page is this simple method:

```
private void MakeSound(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```

All right, everything is fine.

But on my `SettingsSample.xaml` I have a ListBoxItem that calls the method MakeSoundvia `SelectionChanged` property. VS studio tells me that 'event handler MakeSoundis not found on class PhoneApp.SettingsSample '

The code for this page begins with:

```
namespace PhoneApp
{
    public partial class SettingsSample : PhoneApplicationPage { /* snip */ }
}
```

Copying the code of the method on `SettingsPage.xaml.cs` doesn't work ***for some reason***, but I feel like it should possible to use the method described on `MaingePage.xaml.cs`, especially since **their respective code resides in the same Namespace**.

I tried to add

```
using PhoneApp;
```

on SettingsSample.xaml.cs.  Not exceptionally clever, but I have no other idea

Comment: *VS studio tells me that 'event handler makeasound is not found on class PhoneApp.SettingsSample '* It sounds like you're trying to use `MainPage.makeasound` in `SettingsSample`? *I feel like it should possible to use the method ... since their respective code resides in the same Namespace.* Methods belong to classes, inside namespaces.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you see how I could do it, please tell me. Thank you

Comment: Your failing is that you don't understand how object oriented languages (like C#) work.  You should grab you a copy of CLR Via C# immediately and read that puppy (skip the first couple chapters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event function should read `EventClickOnMyListBox` and be located in the code-behind for your page. This function would then call your `makeasound` function (that you can put wherever you want). And it could be called by another event or function.

There is a semantics distinction between the event itself and what the event does. Your event *is not* `makeasound`, your event *will cause* a sound to be made, among possible other things.

If ever you want to add a popup to add a visual effect, you'll be stuck if you called directly the `makeasound` function, whereas you'll just have to add a line to your `EventClickOnMyListBox` in the other scenario.

That's why xaml works that way, and allows you to refer only to object in the enclosing class (or if there is a way I don't know it / and never needed it). You should minimize code-behind code (this is the way of thinking of the [MVVM pattern](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) if you want to go further down this road).

---

Replying to your comment, here is some code to get you started:

Your event should be in the code-behind of your `SettingSample` page, and should call the `makeasound` function instead of *being* the `makeasound` function:

```cs
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Whatever.Myclass.MakeASound (blabla); // So typically MakeASound would be static
}
```

And now same thing in your main page: you do not use your `private void MakeSound(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)` as the event for a click, but an event handler just as the one above.

Take a step back and you'll see it's very natural: you want two things to do the same. But one thing cannot *be* the exact same thing as the first, for language-related reasons (read about C# and XAML to understand why).

So you put your feature in a third component, accessible from the first two. And you call this component from each of them. This way, they both share access to the same feature, and everybody is happy.

Comment: HI Mic, thanks a lot for your answer, but I'm affraid my brain cannot process it...Could you show me some code so that I see how you do that? That would be really nice. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Everybody is happy, espcially me! I deeply thank you for your time and wish you the best. Yesterday my c# book arrived and I spent several hours in it. I love it. Thanks again, I really appreciate.